# Data table modify column css on inline edit

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have few columns on the data table which has pretty long contents and displaying them wrapped when they appear on the data table,

[image]

What I am trying to do is when it triggers "inline edit" then it should show column contents un-wrapped in one single line. For now, it's showing something like,

[image]

Is it possible to modify css of the column to "no wrap" when inline edit event triggers?

Answer (score 0):

If I got your point, why don't you do it this way:

```
//when event "inline_edit" is triggered in an td
$( "td" ).on("inline_edit", function (){
    //change the CSS values for that td
    $( this ).css( "white-space", "nowrap" );
});
```

Comment: Thanks, This won't work the way data table event triggers.